# Mysql: Count monthly distinct user_ids only when date are not same

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

Table

```
-------------------------
  id | user_id | date
------------------------
  1     1         2017-09-12
  2     1         2017-09-12
  3     1         2017-09-13
  4     2         2017-09-14
  5     2         2017-09-15
---------------------------
```

I want to return monthly record with user counts.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS date_period, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS c 
  FROM stats GROUP by date_period
```

This above query returns count as 2 for 2017-09 , but i want to avoid duplicate user_id/date only on daily basis.

```
  id | user_id | date
  1     1         2017-09-12
  2     1         2017-09-12
```

The above rows should be counted as 1 because it's same user and same date

```
  id | user_id | date
 3     1         2017-09-13
```

The above record is user_id => 1 but different day so it should be counted.

```
  id | user_id | date
  4     2         2017-09-14
  5     2         2017-09-15
```

User_id => 2 has two rows on different dates so it should be counted as 2

1 +1 + 2 = 4

The result of count should be 4.

I am stuck with query to return monthly user_id (avoiding duplicate records on same day)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS 'sum_month',
user_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id,date) AS 'Count'
FROM test
GROUP BY sum_month,user_id;
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Get the distinct rows per user_id,date combination and do the monthly count.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') AS date_period, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date,user_id FROM stats) t
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the other answers make me wonder if I am missing something, but shouldn't this be all you need?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS date_period, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id, date) AS c 
FROM stats 
GROUP by date_period
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL approach would have this as two levels of counting:

```
select sum(dt_cnt) from
    (select user_id, count(distinct date_period) as dt_cnt from stats group by user_id) agg_dts
--group by month ??
```

I guess it's possible that query performance might benefit from summing over the aggregate. You'll have to try that for yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

All three of the answers didnt work for me on SQL server 2012. So i got the following solution working

```
select id,userid,date1 from
  (select distinct rankk,max(id) as id,max(userid) as userid,max(date1) as date1 
   from 
     (select rank() over (order by userid,date1) as rankk,* from stakflow) 
   as alias1
   group by rankk) 
as alias2
```

using rank function in combination with subqueries will allow to filter data on basis of repitition  in a given column